# How to sort that query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Probably it's very easy but it seems like I can't figure it out...

How do I sort that query ACS:

```
@most_valuable_clients = current_user.clients.includes(:treatments).group(:vorname, :nachname, "clients.id").sum(:preis)
```

This query produces a hash - I can call query.to_a.sort_by() on it but it slows down everything.

**right now it's like:**

```
1. john 21 dollar
2. mary 25 dollar
3. bob 30 dollar
```

**It should be:**

```
1. bob 30 dollar
2. mary 25 dollar
3. john 21 dollar
```

preis is basically integers and I want to sort them.
I know that I have to use **order** but all I got are errors.

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `order` before `SUM`

```
@most_valuable_clients = current_user.clients.includes(:treatments).group(:vorname, :nachname, "clients.id").order('SUM(preis) DESC').sum(:preis)
```